# Update scrapy on windows

Tags: python, version, scrapy, updates

I really am beginner on both scrapy and python :

I have Scrapy installed on my windows pc, I'd like to update it to the latest version (Scrapy 0.24 I guess), I actually have version 0.22,  would it be possible to do it from the terminal? What should I do?

markoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install scrapy in the first place? If you used pip, run CMD as admin, then try

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
```

This should update your installation to the latest version. To know how to install pip on windows, refer: [How to install pip on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/3297280)

Comment: I installed Scrapy with the easy_install. I did not really understand how the pip works. Any way the easy_install --upgrade Scrapy worked perfectelly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install --upgrade Scrapy
```

did the trick!